# Is it possible to retrieve simple left, right, straight outputs for bicycle routes?

Tags: google-maps, navigation

can I use the Directions Service (or any other one I might have overseen) of Google Maps to retrieve simple outputs (left, right, straight) whenever they occur during bicycle navigation?

For example, an application uses Google Maps to send a specific signal whenever one has to go left, right, straight.

Thanks!